# Inequality book suggestion for basic level

Tags: inequality, reference-request, book-recommendation

I don't know if it is the right platform to ask this. (Forgive me if not.) But I need to study about inequalities and inequality solving methods from a very basic level. I can not figure out under which book title (Algebra Or Calculus) inequality chapter comes. That's why it became very much difficult to find right book on google search. Please suggest me some books of inequality for the elementary study.

$\boldsymbol{Very}$ $\boldsymbol{Basic}\boldsymbol{Level}$$\Longrightarrow$I
am studying differential calculus for postgraduate entrence exam.I need
to find domain and range of given funtion.This is the topic where
i need to get acquainted with the methods of sloving inequality equation
for x(say)

Here are few problems$\Longrightarrow$1. $\frac{1+(log_{a}x)^{2}}{1+log_{a}x}\succ1$,0$\prec a\prec1$

2. 3sin2x$\succ$sinx + cosx+1
3. log$_{\sqrt{2x^{2}-7x+6}}$($\frac{x}{3})\succ0$

4.log$_{3}\frac{|x^{2}-4x|}{x^{2}+|x-5|}\geq0$

Here i need to find the interval where x may belong.So Please suggest
me a book that helps in solving every kind of equation like quadratic,transcedental,exponential,logrithmic
etc.

Comment: I have edited title to make clear that you are interested in basic level introduction. (It seems that the answers posted so far are mostly about contest-level inequalities.) It would probably be helpful if you clarified what you mean by *very basic level.* (If you find it difficult to describe, perhaps even including some examples of problems you hope to be able to solve after learning from the book would be a possible way to do that.)

Comment: This older question seems related: [Books for inequality proofs](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/919688).

Comment: @MartinSleziak as per your advice i tried to make it cear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try **HOW TO LEARN CALCULUS OF ONE VARIABLE BY J.D. GHOSH** IT HAS EXACTLY WHAT YOU NEED. It contains very sharp methods of solving inequality

Answer (score 7):

This [document](http://web.mit.edu/aerblugo/www/A_Brief_Introduction_to_Inequalities.pdf)  may be useful.

I suggest this link of [AoPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Inequality) and the following books:

- *The Cauchy-Schwarz Master Class: An Introduction to the Art of Mathematical Inequalities* by J. Michael Steele.
- Radmila Bulajich Manfrino *Inequalities: A Mathematical Olympiad Approach*
- Basics of Olympiad Inequalities (Samin Riasat) *www.aam.org.in/site/st_material/14.pdf*
- Zdravko Cvetkovski *Inequalities: Theorems, Techniques and Selected Problems*
- *Inequalities* by Hardy/Littlewood/Pólya
- *Introduction to Inequalities* by Beckenbach/Bellman
- *Geometric Inequalities* by Kazarinoff

Comment: please the see the question and suggest accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Try this book:

*Secrets of inequalities vol. 1*, by Pham Kim Hung

The author was an IMO gold medalist. But it was written when he finished his high school so the writing style is very easy to understand.

Vol 1 is suitable for beginners, you then can go on to vol 2.

Comment: Please the see the question and suggest accordingly